# Regex - Filename may contains parantheses group

Tags: regex

I want to match the main name and the file count without parantheses.

For example:

8680733046449.png

8680733046449 (3).png

these files has the same name. I want to seperate second file's name (8680733046449) and the file count (3) (without parantheses).

If file name is not containing any parantheses just match the name.

My regex is:

```
/^(.*)\s?\((\d+)\)\.png$/
```

This regex matching files that has parantheses but the without.

Test here : http://www.regexr.com/38pup

Comment: `^(.*?)(?:\s?\((\d+)\))?\.png$`

Comment: Down vote? Why :D Sometimes i really don't understand you guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a non-greedy quantifier for the name part. Otherwise, it will match the space and parentheses. You also need to make the part in parentheses optional.

```
/^(.*?)\s?(\((\d+)\))?\.png$/
     ^
```

Comment: Not working... Does not match the main file without parantheses

Comment: OK, try it now, I made the parenthesized part optional.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood to you well, I think this would work for you:

```
^(.+)(\s?\((\d+)\))?\.png$
```

Notice that I changed the * after the first dot to avoid empty filenames.

Kind regards.

Comment: matching only the file name... (first one without parantheses)

Comment: Why are you using square brackets? That just matches a single character.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I was wrong. I'm going to edit the answer.